# Intercept getter and setter calls in Rails for data manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with a Rails/Angular application that stores temperature values. Temperatures are always stored in Celsius in the database. These temperature values can be displayed to the user in either Celsius or Fahrenheit based on the user's preference.

The application can also alert the user if a temperature reaches a certain value. That is important because a user might enter an alert value in Fahrenheit, but it needs to be converted to Celsius before it is stored in the database. These `alert` values are also in a different table than the temperature readings themselves, so the solution is ideally applicable across models.

So, essentially, **I need to find the best location and strategy for manipulating values when they are read *and saved* to the database**. We've tried a couple different things, but I am looking to refactor these into a nice maintainable solution that involves as few code paths as possible.

For the display-time change of temperature readings, we've used a controller concern in the `ReadingsController`. That maps to a `ReadingPresenter` that will convert to Fahrenheit if the user has that preference.

```
class ReadingPresenter
  include ApplicationHelper

  def initialize(sensor_reading, sample_type)
    @model = sensor_reading
    @sample_type = sample_type
  end

  def value
    if @sample_type.temperature?
      TemperatureService.for_current_user @model.value
    else
      @model.value
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine when we need to display a Fahrenheit reading that is already stored, but since it is a presenter it will obviously not work when we need to change a user-entered Fahrenheit `alert` value to Celsius to be stored in the database.

In that case, we've created a model concern that has `before_save`, `after_save`, and `after_find` callbacks to manipulate.

```
module TemperatureAttributes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def temperatures(*temperature_attributes)
      options = temperature_attributes.extract_options!
      before_save TemperatureScaleConverter.new(temperature_attributes, options[:if])
      after_save TemperatureScaleConverter.new(temperature_attributes, options[:if])
      after_find TemperatureScaleConverter.new(temperature_attributes, options[:if])
    end
  end
end
```

This does work, but you can see that it is a completely different code path. I have to imagine there is a better way to handle this type of situation in Rails.

I've been experimenting with [Ruby's prepend method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-prepended) to intercept the calls and have also considered using `alias_method_chain` in a similar way. I have also thought of trying to conditionally use database views to convert the values at the lowest level possible.

I'm not looking for you to solve my problem for me, but **if you have any advice on the best way to intercept getter and setter calls in Rails across models** I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making some things more difficult than they have to be while also hinting at using some nice patterns.

First issue is your use of callbacks ... I think that what you want is to use an after_initialize ...

```
 class ReadingPresenter
      ...
      after_initialize :presentation_value

      def presentation_value
           TemperatureService.for_current_user @model.value
      end
```

And then use this presentation_value instead of value. (I am assuming there is a good reason to have the ReadingPresenter class rather than just working with some model like Temperature < ActiveRecord::Base).

I think you are probably making the right decision to use a service to handle the presentation value, especially as I can imagine that draws status from other parts of your app. I also think that a lot of your logic in the callbacks is beside the point and is better handled by using something like after_initialize. But it also seems odd that you are not just managing the presentation of the Temperature object, that you could handle a little more atomically than handling your presentation as a 'thing' unto itself.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer - I appreciate it. I like your use of `after_initialize` in a Presenter object. I didn't think of that. Unless I'm misunderstanding, I couldn't use the `after_initialize` block to help with **setting** the value in Celsius when a Fahrenheit value is passed in, right?

Comment: It's a little tough to answer without seeing the whole code base, and my answer is vague as a result. I think you are right, but I think that a lot of problems go away if you use Temperature < ActiveRecord::Base, and use after_initialize to ensure the value is in C. You started off by talking about getter and setters, but you are using them on a helper class (if I am understanding) when they probably are better used on a model that is significant to your app.